# Аргументы функции main

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте, меня интересует main функция с параметрами, часто вижу запись в чужых исходниках, да и в своих (пишу эту часть неосознанно)

```
 int main(int argc, char **argv)
```

Как эти параметры передаются в функцию при ее вызове и что они вобще значат, спасибо.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это параметры, которые передаются программе при запуске.

argc - количество этих параметров.  argv - указатель на массив указателей на строки, каждая из которых содержит один параметр. Параметры передаются в виде строк Си. Еще бывает такая запись - char* argv[]

В структуре памяти процесса Линукса они находятся в стеке сразу за стеком функции main. Думаю, в других системах то же устройство.

Answer (score 4):

Вам тут показали на примерах. Забыли правда про третий параметр main() ссылку на вектор переменных окружения ОС (environment, те, которые в Shell устанавливаются командой export).

Вообще полностью:

```
int main (int ac, char **argv, char **env)
```

Почитайте также man execl.

Comment: Лень искать описания c++, а в ISO/IEC 9899:1999 (E) (это про C99) количество аргументов main -- 0 или 2. Раздел 5.1.2.2.1 Program startup

Comment: N3291 3.6.1.1
All implementations shall allow both of the following definitions of main:
int main() { /* ... */ }
and
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { /* ... */ }

Comment: Очевидно, что на практике можно определять 0,1,2 или 3 параметра в main().

Не знаю, как там правильно по вашей документации, но программка работает.

    #include  <stdio.h>
    #include  <stdlib.h>
    
    main (int ac, char *av[], char *ev[])
    {
      int i;
    
      for (i = 0; ev[i]; i++)
        printf ("%s\n",ev[i]);
    
      printf ("environment %d items\n",i);
    
      exit(0);
    }

и всегда такие работали и в \*nix и в Windows. Уверен, что в VAX/VMS тоже работает. Про забытую экзотику, типа RT-11 не знаю.

Comment: Википедия http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_function утверждает, что unix (но не POSIX.1) и MS Windows.

Comment: Ну вот и разобрались ! Хорошая ссылка. Не знал о четвертом аргементе в apple. 

Спасибо !

Answer (score 3):

Если ваша прога будет называться **myprog**, то допустим вы вызываете ее с параметрами так:

**myprog param1, param2, param3**

Соответственно в `main()` вы получите:

```
argc=3 //количество параметров
argv[0]="param1"; //1-й параметр
argv[1]="param2"  //2-й параметр
argv[3]="param3"  //3-й параметр
```

При этом если при завершении проги вы вернете в `main()` `return 2;`
то ось получит exit code равное 2 (в Windows это называется `errorlevel`)

**Update**
Спорол лажу с примером - исправляю:

**myprog param1 param2 param3**

Соответственно в `main()` вы получите:

```
argc=4 //количество параметров
argv[0]="myprog"; //название запускаемого файла
argv[1]="param1"  //1-й параметр
argv[2]="param2"  //2-й параметр
argv[3]="param3"  //3-й параметр
```

Comment: пример неверный

Comment: Это правильно для Джавы. В С/С++ по соглашению argv[0] - имя программы.

Comment: А кто скушал запятые? @mikillskegg Для джабы, говорите? А откуда взялся `argc`? Вероятно там где-то `argc=argv.lenght` в кустах...

Comment: Да лажанулся - бывает. Давно не брал в руки С/С++ и с запятыми напутал :) Щаз поправлю

Comment: Хотя, на самом деле, запускающих процесс может в argv[0] вставить все, что угодно )))

Comment: @Barmaley, жаба душит? ))))

Answer (score 2):

Это стандртная вещь в C/C++

- argc - количество аргументов в командной строке
- *argv[] - массив указателей на строки, содержащие эти аргументы

При этом argv[0] - это имя команды, а argv[argc] - это NULL.

Answer (score 2):

baz.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::cout << "argc: " << argc << "\n";
    for (int i =0; i < argc; ++i)
        std::cout << i << ": " << argv[i] << "\n";
}
```

Смотрим:

```
$ g++ baz.cpp -o boo
$ ./boo foo
argc: 2
0: ./boo
1: foo
```

Comment: А что значат эти параметры?

Comment: [Ничего существенного (:][1]

  [1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F

Comment: А можно и так их вывести:

copy (argv, argv+argc, ostream_iterator<char*> (cout , "\n"));

Comment: `while(argc--) cout << *argv++ << endl;`

Comment: Тоже можно.

Comment: Эти параметры передает система?

Comment: Передает система, но определяет родительский процесс

Comment: Операционные системы, они разные бывают (или были?). Видел, как такими делами занимался сишный рантайм... (decus C для pdp-11 & vms-11)

Comment: @mikillskegg, @alexlz, согласен, ваши варианты ваши варианты в данном случае подходят гораздо лучше

Comment: Да нет, нормальный, стандартный вариант. В информатике очень многие задачи можно решить разными способами.

Comment: @alexlz, сейчас, наверное, 99.9% ОС - либо винды, либо никсы какие-нибудь

Comment: Совсем Contiki запинали... В 90е годы самой распространённой ос была OS/2. За счёт банкоматов (они тогда под ней вроде работали)

Comment: А еще раньше их было еще больше )))